# Save JPEG in Grayscale color mode

Tags: c#, image-processing

I'm trying to save a JPEG as a grayscale image.

I found the code below that will *make* it grayscale by blending the channels, but it still has all three RGB channels. I only need one 8 bit channel.

```
    public static Bitmap MakeGrayscale(Bitmap original)
    {
        //create a blank bitmap the same size as original
        Bitmap newBitmap = new Bitmap(original.Width, original.Height);

        //get a graphics object from the new image
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(newBitmap);

        //create the grayscale ColorMatrix
        ColorMatrix colorMatrix = new ColorMatrix(
           new float[][] 
          {
             new float[] {.3f, .3f, .3f, 0, 0},
             new float[] {.59f, .59f, .59f, 0, 0},
             new float[] {.11f, .11f, .11f, 0, 0},
             new float[] {0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
             new float[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}
          });

        //create some image attributes
        ImageAttributes attributes = new ImageAttributes();

        //set the color matrix attribute
        attributes.SetColorMatrix(colorMatrix);

        //draw the original image on the new image
        //using the grayscale color matrix
        g.DrawImage(original, new Rectangle(0, 0, original.Width, original.Height),
           0, 0, original.Width, original.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, attributes);

        //dispose the Graphics object
        g.Dispose();
        return newBitmap;
    }
```

Is there any way in C# to actually set the color mode of JPEG?

I've tried the following, but it still outputs a 24 bit RGB image.

```
            ImageCodecInfo codec = GetEncoderInfo("image/jpeg");
            System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder enc = System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.ColorDepth;
            EncoderParameters encParams = new EncoderParameters(1);
            encParams.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(enc, 8L);

            source_bitmap.Save(outputFile, codec, encParams);
```

Comment: Not directly related to your code but may help http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/70442/C-RGB-to-Palette-Based-8-bit-Greyscale-Bitmap-Clas

Answer (score 1):

There are different greyscales which can be compiled as a linear combination of the three channels in your image.

The most commonly used is 'Luminosity' but it differs depending on your image. [See this](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2009/08/24/algorithms-convert-color-grayscale/)

To convert to Luminosity greyscale take

```
greyscale = 0.21 * R + 0.71 * G + 0.07 * B
```

Where R, G and B are your red, green and blue channels respectively and given that they are on a scale of 0 to 1. If they are on a 255 scale, divide by 255